# Connect docker-container with other container by unit-socket

Tags: docker, postgresql, unix-sockets, container, connectivity

I'am trying to connect to containers by unit-socket/

```
 docker run -d -v /var/lib/docker/overlay/[container_id]/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432:/socket_volume/.s.PGSQL.5432 -p 50000:8080 my_repo/container_name:latest
```

In a place of host at '-v construction' I writed absolulely path from host-root to socket-directory in container.

But I received:

```
  Connection refused (socket: /socket_volume/.s.PGSQL.5432)
```

Comment: What OS? Last time I tried this socket sharing was only supported on Linux - did not work on mac.

Comment: Its a Linux. Not Mac

Comment: jordanm, could you share with me you experience?